# Fill combobox with immense entrys results in browser crash

Tags: html, browser, combobox, crash

I got a Combobox on a HTML- Site and this got 192.300 entrys.
Every single option is named this way in the source:

`<option value="1">1 Test</option>
 <option value="2">2 Test</option>
 <option value="3">3 Test</option>`

I think the Browser crashes because of to many code.
Is there another way to get the entrys into the Combobox without crashing the browser?

Comment: Generally drop-downs are not used for such huge entries. I suggest you to tell us your requirement.

Comment: These are Database records from another Program. And the WebApplication displays them on the site

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason to use a HTML drop-down. If it flexible then please use type-ahead/autosuggest which will populate a custom drop-down based on the entered text.

This will also improve on the UX as it is an effort to find something from a dropdown which contains lot of items.

Comment: These are Database records from another Program. And the WebApplication displays them on the site. The User is able to filter the entrys